# Control the position of the icon in a QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qstyle

I've subclassed `QStyle` to control the aspect of my app. After customizing the aspect of the `QLineEdits`, I need to add an icon inside the `QLineEdit` and it has to be clickable by the user. I've seen that I can use the method `QLineEdit::addAction` to add an action and an icon in the `QLineEdit`. The problem arises with the position in which it draws the icon because as I have the customized `QLineEdit`, the icon draws too near the edge of `QLineEdit`. I need to separate more icon `QLineEdit` edge. Does anyone know how to control the position of the icon in the `QLineEdit`?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information with regard to precisely *how* your custom style affects the `QLineEdit`.  If you don't apply your custom style does the problem still exist?

Comment: No, if I don't apply my custom style, the problem dissapears. The custom style applies a shadow when the user set the focus on him and the edge of the control is more inward. For this reason, I think Qt  set the icon from the shadow of the QLineEdit, not from the edge and then the icon appears too near to the edge